# Bloomberg field name to get implied volatility of options

Tags: options, implied-volatility, bloomberg

I am trying to get option data from bloomberg api. I got the all available options on a given underlying eg:"ASML NA" and Field "PX_LAST" gave the last traded price for each option. Is there a similar field to get the implied volatility?

Comment: On a terminal, type ASML NA Equity Go then "FLDS implied" Go and that will give you a list of fields, such as `3MO_CALL_IMP_VOL` - if you want the implied vol of a specific option use that option's ticker instead and there will be more option specific fields.

Comment: Best to ask the help desk with questions like that (F1F1).

Comment: You could also emply BQL to get the options of interest for an underlying, and pull all data you like in one go. E.g. =BQL.Query("get(strike_px(), ivol(), delta(), gamma(), vega(), rho()) for(filter(options('IBM US Equity'), expire_dt() <3M and pct_moneyness() > 100 and pct_moneyness() < 110 and put_call()=='Call')) with(fill='PREV') will get you strike, IV, delta, gamma, vega and rho for all IBM US options that currently epxiry in <3m and are filtered by moneyness levels.